# Bootstrap data-toggle="tab" calling in a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, href

I have a little problem with some JavaScript code that I fail to call in a function. The code is:

```js
$('#myTabs a[href="#name"]').tab('show');
```

It works if it is not called in a function. This is supposed to toggle tabs working with Bootstrap framework. Does anyone know how to make it compatible to call in a function?

Edit:

```
function switch_tab()
{
   $('#tablist a[href="#tab_default_2"]').tab('show');
}
```

Does not work while it does work without function. (I'm not good in JavaScript, so if it's obvious, I may not have seen it).

Comment: Can you show us an example (code) of what does not work?

Comment: could you pleas provide all code of your function?

Comment: @kmsdev After some hard trying, I found what did not work.

Comment: @Tripesdeporc What didn't work? Update your post or make a reply with the solution.

Comment: @kmsdev It is already in the edit of the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Code of the tablist :

```
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs " id="tablist">
                    <li class="active" id="li_tab1">
                        <a href="#tab_default_1" data-toggle="tab" id="tab1">
                        Situation administrative </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="li_tab2">
                        <a href="#tab_default_2" data-toggle="tab" id="tab2">
                        Demande de temps partiel </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="li_tab3">
                        <a href="#tab_default_3" data-toggle="tab" id="tab3">
                        Envoi de la demande </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Code of the button :

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="change_formulaire" onclick="switch_tab();" data-toggle="tab">Valider</button>
```

And code of the full function :

```
            function switch_tab()
        {
            document.getElementById("tab1").disabled=true;
            document.getElementById("tab1").style.color="grey";
            document.getElementById("li_tab1").className="active";
            document.getElementById("tab2").disabled=false;
            document.getElementById("tab2").style.color="";
            document.getElementById("li_tab2").className="active";
            $('#tablist a[href="#tab_default_2"]').tab('show');
        }
```

Edit :
Here is the solution : In the function, you can't switch to a tab if it is active. So you have to make it active (for the display) after you swiched.
So the function now looks like this :

```
function switch_tab()
        {
            document.getElementById("tab1").disabled=true;
            document.getElementById("tab1").style.color="grey";
            document.getElementById("li_tab1").className="active";
            document.getElementById("tab2").disabled=false;
            document.getElementById("tab2").style.color="";
            $('#tablist a[href="#tab_default_2"]').tab('show');
            document.getElementById("li_tab2").className="active";
        }
```